# How to synchronize sqlite3 update with command execution

Tags: node.js, express, service, sqlite

I am working with a NodeJS project where i need to update a table and afterwards restart a service. Unfortunately the service restarts before the table has been updated. So i assume this is a normal async behaviour.

How do i synchronize this?

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('/home/test/testApp.db', 'OPEN_READWRITE');

router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { data: dbConfigRow });
})
.post(function(req, res) {
    // console.log(req.body);
    db.serialize(function() {
        for (var key in req.body) {
            db.run("UPDATE config SET " + key + "='" + req.body[key] + "'");
        }
        exec('systemctl restart demoApp');
    });
    res.json(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or any one of the popular promise libraries ([When.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when), [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)).

Any of these should solve your problem.  In Async it might look something like this using [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback):

```
.post(function(req, res) {
   async.series([
     function(callback){
       db.serialize(function() {
         for (var key in req.body) {
           db.run("UPDATE config SET " + key + "='" + req.body[key] + "'");
         }
         callback()
      })
    },
    function(callback){
      exec('systemctl restart demoApp'); //Assuming this is synchronous 
      callback()
    }
    ],
    function(error, results){ //Using the optional callback
      res.send(200);
    }
  );
});
```

This assumes `db.run` is synchronous (it looks like it is).

All this said, it looks like your current implementation was returning 200 before it finished all the db/restarting tasks.  You might try moving the response after the `exec`.  That may also work.  Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Works like a charm! A parentheses is missing in the end of the `db.serialize` function, except that everything is fine.

Comment: Ah, missed that, thanks!  I've edited my answer to include the parenthesis.  If you found my answer solved your issue, please accept it.  Otherwise, let me know if I can help with anything else!